# Trying to make a dynamic chart that ignores blank cells made with formula IFBLANK

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to make a dynamic chart that ignores blank cells made with formula IFBLANK. To find the last row I'm currently using .END(xlUp).Row but because the blank cells are not really blank due to the formula, it is not ignored when the chart is made. How can I make the chart so that these cells are ignored? The chart is made in a sheet where the data is sourced from another sheet.

Code:

```
Dim chtObj As ChartObject

Dim Calculation As Worksheet

lr = Worksheets("Calculation").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
lc = Worksheets("Calculation").Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Set chtRng = Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(lr, lc))

Set ChartArea = Range("b" & lr + 3 & ":j" & lr + 20)
Worksheets("Calculation").Shapes.AddChart2(317, xlRadarMarkers).Select
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=chtRng
Set chtObj = ActiveChart.Parent


chtObj.Top = ChartArea.Top
chtObj.Left = ChartArea.Left
chtObj.Height = ChartArea.Height
chtObj.Width = ChartArea.Width
```

Pictures of the excel sheet:
[image]

IfBlank formula:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter all the blanks from the range and then plot the chart to avoid this problem.

P.S: Consider this,

[image]

```
Sub test()
    With ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add _
         (Left:=100, Width:=375, Top:=75, Height:=225)
        .Chart.SetSourceData Source:=Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Range("D2").Value)
        .Chart.ChartType = xlLine
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the input! Sorry if I wasn't clear enough but I want to ignore the cells so that they are not included in the chart. By using your formula it is still included

Comment: Thanks again. But since the cell are not actually blank but only appears blank it is still included when using the Counta function :/

Comment: @FrederikBaungårdChristiansen Updated the formula give it a try now.

Comment: Hi Imran. Yeah that help with ignoring the blanks. The problem is that when it is not blank it should show the text from the sourced cell. With your formula IF(B6="";==) it just shows FALSE when there is some text in it. That is why I have used IF(ISBLANK(Sheet2!A23); " ";Sheet2!A23)

Comment: I made it work by adding: =IF(Sheet2!A23 = "";"";Sheet2!A23).  Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

From the select data choice for your chart, you can go to handling of hidden or empty cells in your chart, to choose how such cells are handled. Does that fix your problem?

[image]

For just continuing up your table until you come to a cell which is not a space, insert this code below the line where you set the initial value of `lr`:

```
Do While lr > 1 And Len(Trim(Worksheets("Calculation").Cells(lr, 1))) = 0
    lr = lr - 1
    Debug.Print lr
Loop
```

If you change the if-statement to return "" instead of " " when true, you won't need the `Trim` either (come to think of it, I could just have compared to 1 instead of to 0 too).

Comment: Hi Eirikdaude,Thank for your input but I need to generate the chart using macros so I need to implement it in the VBA

Comment: @FrederikBaungårdChristiansen Have you tried recording what happens when you change those values with the macro recorder? I suspect it is just some property you need to change for the dataseries, if the approach otherwise works.

Comment: Good point with recording the macro but the setting is already the same as in your picture and nothing happens when I try to change it.

Comment: @FrederikBaungårdChristiansen Try the solution I suggest under the picture then, it seems to work for me :)